# About shell and subshell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to shell,I just learned that use (command) will create a new subshell and exec the command, so I try to print the pid of father shell and subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $$
echo "`echo $$`"
sleep 4
var=$(echo $$;sleep 4)
echo $var
```

But the answer is:

```
$./test.sh
9098
9098
9098
```

My questions are:

1. Why just three echo prints? There are 4 echos in my code.
2. Why three pids are the same? subshell's pid is obviously not same with his father's.

Thanks a lot for answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the assignment *captures* standard output of the child and puts it into `var`, rather than printing it:

```
var=$(echo $$;sleep 4)
```

This can be seen with:

```
$ xyzzy=$(echo hello)
$ echo $xyzzy
hello
```

Secondly, all those `$$` variables are evaluated in the *current* shell which means they're turned into the current PID *before* any children start. The children see the PID that has already been generated. In other words, the children are executing `echo 9098` rather than `echo $$`.

If you want the PID of the child, you have to prevent translation in the parent, such as by using single quotes:

```
bash -c 'echo $$'
```

Comment: If you consult "man bash", the information in paxdiablo's answer is found under headings Command Substitution and Special Parameters.

Comment: I would add two things: 1. that there are *5* echos in the code, two of which are captured as strings (one echo'd immediately, the other stored in var).  2. In bash 4.0 and higher, the environment variable "$BASHPID" will print out the PID of the subshell.  Bash 4.0 is not yet common, try bash --version to see yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "one.sh $$"
echo `eval echo '$$'`
```

I am expecting the above to print different pids, but it doesn't. It's creating a child process. Verified by adding sleep in **``**.

```
echo "one.sh $$"
echo `eval "echo '$$'";sleep 10`
```

On executing the above from a script and running **ps** shows two processs one.sh(name of the script) and sleep.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
test    12685  0.0  0.0   8720  1012 pts/15   S+   13:50   0:00      \_ bash one.sh
test    12686  0.0  0.0   8720   604 pts/15   S+   13:50   0:00          \_ bash one.sh
test    12687  0.0  0.0   3804   452 pts/15   S+   13:50   0:00              \_ sleep 10
```

This is the output produced

```
one.sh 12685
12685
```

Not sure what i am missing.

Comment: Bash is sneaky, decides what `$$` expands to at startup and then keeps it in all the subshells it forks.  (This is, as far as I know, intentional, to make the expansion stay the same, e.g., for naming temporary files.)

Comment: [It's coz of this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858191/difference-between-bash-pid-and)

Answer (score -1):

The solution is `$!`. As in:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "parent" $$
yes > /dev/null &
echo "child" $!
```

Output:

```
$ ./prueba.sh
parent 30207
child 30209
```