# Why is $$ in a subshell equal to $$ in the parent shell?

Tags: shell

```
#! /bin/bash

func1()
{
        echo $$
}

echo $$
( func1 )
```

This gives the result:

```
9644
9644
```

I expected that they would be different. Can anyone please explain why they are not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get pid of current subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725925/get-pid-of-current-subshell)

Comment: This is mandated by POSIX, presumably for uniformity since a shell isn't required to create a new process for a subshell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the section `PARAMETER EXPANSION` of `man bash`:

> $      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  **In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.**

This is also mandated by the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> $
>   Expands to the decimal process ID of the invoked shell. In a subshell (see Shell Execution Environment ), '$' shall expand to the same value as that of the current shell.

If you want the process ID of the subshell, use `$BASHPID`:

```
func1() { echo $BASHPID; }
echo $BASHPID
28365
( func1 )
28627
```